# Check different radio buttons at the same time with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, radio-button, radio-group

I have two groups of radio buttons.
I would like to when I click in one buttom of a group, select automaticaly the corresponding button in the another group at the same time. How I do that with jquery? I tried many ways, no success.

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="A" id="A">A
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="B" id="B">B
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="A1" id="A1">A1
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="B1" id="B1">B1

<script>
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
    // if check A, check A1 too
    // if check B, check B1 too
    // if check A1, check A too
    // if check B1, check B too
   })
</script>
```

Here´s the jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/F9LYL/](http://jsfiddle.net/F9LYL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest associating the 'corresponding' elements somehow, I've used a class in this approach, giving the HTML:

```
<input class="A" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="A" id="A">A
<input class="B" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="B" id="B">B
<br><br>
<input class="A" type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="A1" id="A1">A1
<input class="B" type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="B1" id="B1">B1
```

Which allows the following jQuery to work:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    $('.' + this.className).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F9LYL/1/).

Or with a custom `data-*` attribute:

```
<input data-group="A" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="A" id="A">A
<input data-group="B" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="B" id="B">B
<br><br>
<input data-group="A" type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="A1" id="A1">A1
<input data-group="B" type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="B1" id="B1">B1
```

With the following jQuery, using an `attribute-equals` selector:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    $('[data-group="' + $(this).data('group') + '"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F9LYL/3/).

Similarly you could also wrap the elements into individual groups:

```
<fieldset>
    <input data-group="A" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="A" id="A" />A
    <input data-group="B" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="B" id="B" />B
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <input data-group="A" type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="A1" id="A1" />A1
    <input data-group="B" type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="B1" id="B1" />B1
</fieldset>
```

And use:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F9LYL/8/).

Incidentally, if you wrap the associated text into a `label` element (with the `for` attribute) as it *should* be, to give:

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="A" id="A"><label for="A">A</label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="B" id="B"><label for="B">B</label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="A1" id="A1"><label for="A1">A1</label>
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="B1" id="B1"><label for="B1">B1</label>
```

Then the following jQuery will first create the appropriate wrapping and then use the `index()` method to correctly identify the appropriate *other* radio `input`s to check:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
    if (!(this.parentNode instanceof HTMLFieldSetElement)) {
        var fieldset = $('<fieldset />');
        fieldset.insertBefore(this).append(document.getElementsByName(this.name));
    }
    $(this).after($('label[for="' + this.id + '"]'));
}).change(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F9LYL/10/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName).
  - [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).
  - [Logical 'NOT' (`!`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
- jQuery:

  - [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).
  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Updated with another example for both groups.

Comment: Your first suggestion is the best way for me, a small code with the result I need, thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! Do be aware, though, that selecting by `className` of the changed element does mean that if you add other classes it'll likely stop working (due to the white-space in the string returned by `className` and, potentially, additional classes themselves not being present in the other 'corresponding' elements). I'd really suggest switching to one of the latter approaches for at least *some* future-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/F9LYL/5/)):

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    $('input:radio[id^="'+this.value+'"]').prop('checked', 1);
});
```

**Update:** This one (different) will work by clicking on both groups ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/F9LYL/6/)):

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    $('input:radio[id^="'+this.value[0]+'"]').prop('checked', 1);
});
```

Comment: But if someone clicks an `input` in the second group first, that won't automatically select the element in the first group (I took that approach first and then realised that the string manipulations required to allow clicking later groups would be more work than they're actually worth).

Comment: Works too. Thanks by the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I believe it is very straightforward. See the demo at the bottom:

```
$(function() {
    var radios = $('[name=RadioGroup1],[name=RadioGroup2]');
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var index = $( this ).index( $('[name=' + this.name + ']') );
        radios.not( $('[name=' + this.name + ']') ).eq( index )
        .prop( 'checked', true );
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9LYL/4/)

Works great if you have just two groups. You may have to tweak the code slightly to handle more than two groups of radio buttons.

**EDIT**

The version and demo below are adjusted to handle any number of groups of radio buttons, and you do not have make any changes to your markup:

```
$(function() {
    var radios = $('[name^=RadioGroup]');
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var index = $( this ).index( $('[name=' + this.name + ']') );
        var groups = [];
        radios.not( $('[name=' + this.name + ']') )
        .each(function(v,i) {
            $.inArray(this.name, groups) > -1 || groups.push( this.name );
        });
        $.each(groups, function(i,v) {
            $('[name=' + v + ']').eq( index ).prop( 'checked', true );
        });
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9LYL/9/)

Comment: Works like a charm but I preferred the small code, thank you.