# Check different radio buttons at the same time with jquery [Extension]

Tags: php, jquery, html, foreach, radio-button

I have a problem similar to this resolved question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859486/check-different-radio-buttons-at-the-same-time-with-jquery)! 
There are many great answers in this link even extending the OP's problem to multiple radio groups.

(My formatting is the same as in the link but) my problem is that I don't have more than two radio groups, but rather multiple elements in my radio groups using a FOREACH loop. 
My PHP is below followed by the script.

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT example
FROM example_DB ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    foreach($row as &$value) {
         if ($value == NULL) {
            echo "";
            }
        else {

?>
<form method="post">
<input data-group="A" class="A" type="radio" value="<?php echo"$value<br />\n";?>">
<?phpecho"$value<br />\n";}}}?>
</input>

</div> 
<div>    
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT example
FROM example_DB");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    foreach($row as &$value) {
         if ($value == 0.00) {
            echo "";
            }
        else {
            ?>

<input data-group="A" class="A" ID="A" type="radio" value="<?php echo"$value<br />\n";?>">

<?php
 echo"$value<br />\n";
}}}
?>
</input>  
</div>  

  </form>
```

Im using the script that came with one of the answers in the link:

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function() {
var radios = $('[type=radio]');
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    var index = $( this ).index( $('[name=' + this.name + ']') );
    var groups = [];
    radios.not( $('[name=' + this.name + ']') )
    .each(function(v,i) {
        $.inArray(this.name, groups) > -1 || groups.push( this.name );
    });
    $.each(groups, function(i,v) {
        $('[name=' + v + ']').eq( index ).prop( 'checked', true );
    });
});
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: after selecting any radio button, do you want to check radio button in other group with same name as selected radio button? and don't want to use loop, right?

Comment: I think my code is making this more complex than it needs to be. In the link given, there are two radio groups with two elements each: RG1(A,B) and RG2(A1,B1). Im looking for jquery that works the same, but extends this from two elements to three: RG1(A,B,C) and RG2(A1,B1,C1). Eventually, i will extend this to a number of elements determined by my foreach loop.

Comment: And to answer your question, yes. after selecting any radio button, i want to check radio button in the other group with same name as selected radio button. Sorry for any confusion..

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can read the `name` of selected radio button and find all radio button with same name to select them.

**NOTE** - `$(document).ready(..` and `$(function(){..` both are same, so you can use any one of them and not both at same time.

```
$(function() {
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
      var name = $(this).prop('name');
      $('input:radio[name="'+name+'"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
  });
});
```

**EDIT**- As OP want to select all radio button with same class name or value, use following code -

For Same **Class** -

```
$(function() {
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
      var className = $(this).prop('class');
      $('input:radio[class="'+className +'"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
  });
});
```

For Same **Value** -

```
$(function() {
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
      var radioVal = $(this).val();
      $('input:radio[value="'+ radioVal +'"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm looking to select radio buttons between groups that have different names. I don't think this still work? I tried matching the group names and this doesn't work either.

Comment: rather than matching names, can I match classnames or ID with this code, something that is the same between radio groups?

Comment: thats what i asked you and you said 'i want to check radio button in the other group with same name'...yes you can match classnames but ID is not preferable as you must not use same id for multiple elements.

Comment: please check my EDIT in answer, this should help you. But make sure that this will match exact class name like if you have `class="A"` for selected radio button then it will select other radio button with `class="A"` and not for radio with `class="A B"`

Comment: Sorry, i misinterpreted. check radio button in the other group with same VALUE*
The group names need to be different so i can reference the inputs in the next page.

Comment: I tried your EDIT. I believe this would work if my values were not from a foreach loop. No matter what value i select, it chooses to select the final value of the loop. It does select the last value from both groups at the same time though. Can i fix this by making my classname different for each value in the loop? i can do this by making my classname the actual value.

Comment: Ok, after long coding, i fixed my problem! A big thanks to you Bhushan for the script. The problem was my classes were the same for each iteration of the foreach loop, they needed to be different for each loop, but the same between each group for each particular iteration. Thanks again!